# Possible reason/s for increases in neutrophil, platelet, and WBC levels at the same time?

Tags: blood-tests, test-results, white-blood-count, platelet-count

I took a routine blood test today, and my results came back with three abnormal results that the laboratory flagged.

My WBC, platelet count, and neutrophil levels were all elevated:

- WBC: 11.8
- Platelet Count: 488
- Nuetrophil Level: 8.6

**Are these levels concerning or just slightly elevated? Possible reason/s for increases in neutrophil, platelet, and WBC levels at the same time?**

My GP is currently on vacation --- I called today to see if I should be on treatment, but he's not available for another week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The increased WBC, platelet, and Neutroplil count suggests that your body may be trying to fight off an infection. When the body is under attack, it increases it's white blood cell production to combat the infection. The platelets also suggest an infection, as well as the Neutrophil count, which are a type of white blood cell. The possibility of illness is one out of many, though the most likeley. Though an examination or more blood work can rule out any other causes which may be more severe. If I were in your shoes, I'd consult a doctor who can examine you and do proper tests.